# Inputting and outputing in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, input, output

I have completed the code, but can someone check it for me. I am having trouble outputting the exact output that the sample is suppose to be. My code can't recognize the proper spacing between the names and determine the exact location of the letters. As well as compute the amount of letters correctly without creating other errors.

Program 1: Prompt the user to enter any full name (first middle surname). Do not bother with surnames like O'Reilly, Van Helsing, de Ville etc. Then output the following:

the length of the full name.
the length of the middle name.
the three initials of the name.
the name in all upper case.

**SAMPLE OUT:**

Enter a first name middle name and surname

Peggy Sue Palmer

Length of your name: 16 characters

Length of your middle name: 3 characters

Your initials are PSP

PEGGY SUE PALMER

**My code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program2_1 {

    //private static String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a first name, middle name, and surname:");
        String first_name = user_input.next(); 
        String second_name = user_input.next();
        String surname = user_input.next();
        System.out.println("Length of your name: " + first_name.length() + second_name.length() + surname.length() + " characters");
        System.out.println("Length of your middle name: " + second_name.length() + " characters");
        System.out.println("Your initials are " + first_name.charAt(0)+ second_name.charAt(0)+ surname.charAt(0));
        System.out.println(first_name + second_name + surname);

      }
}
```

Program 2: Write a program that generates two random integers, both in the range 50 to 100, inclusive. Use the Math class. Print both integers and then display the positive difference between the two integers, but use a selection. Do not use the absolute value method of the Math class.

**My code:**

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Program2_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //int num = 50(int)(Math.random()* 51);
        int x = (int)(50 + Math.random()* 51);
        System.out.println("Integer one: " + x);
        int y = (int)(50 + Math.random()*51);
        System.out.println("Integer two: " + y);
        int z = (x - y);
        if (y > x)
            z = (y - x);
            System.out.println("The positive difference between both integer: " + z);           
    }

}
```

Comment: There is also no question asked about the second problem

Comment: Modifying the cast as the other user indicates does make the code look better, however it creates another problem. It only prints output when the condition is true, but when its not it doesn't print out anything just the integers.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems in the second code is that you need to cast if statement.

```
    if (y > x){
       z = (y - x);
       System.out.println("The positive difference between both integer: " + z);
      }
```

Comment: what does "cast if statement" mean?

Comment: if you're referring to adding the braces, what he/she actually wants is to fix the indentation because they probably want to unconditionally print that out

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I really appreciate it. I am new to java and If you have any tips for me please let me know. I added the cast and it made the code look better. However the cast creates another problem. It doesn't output the statement unless its true and if it isn't then it doesn't output. Without the cast it outs the correct difference without a negative.